# jQuery File Upload - configuring and running

Tags: php, jquery, file-upload

I'm using this plugin: [jQuery File Upload](http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/)

My HTML:

```
<input id="fileupload" type="file" name="files[]" data-url="upload.php" multiple>
        <script src="/js/vendor/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
        <script src="/js/jquery.iframe-transport.js"></script>
        <script src="/js/jquery.fileupload.js"></script>
        <script src="http://blueimp.github.com/JavaScript-Load-Image/load-image.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://blueimp.github.com/JavaScript-Canvas-to-Blob/canvas-to-blob.min.js"></script>
        <script src="/js/jquery.fileupload-fp.js"></script>

        <div id="dropzone" class="fade well">Drop files here</div>
```

My JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

                $('#fileupload').fileupload({
                    dataType: 'json',
                    dropZone: $('#dropzone'),
                    singleFileUploads: false,
                    add: function (e, data) {
                        $(this).fileupload('process', data).done(function () {
                            data.submit();
                        });
                    },
                    done: function (e, data) {
                        $.each(data.result, function (index, file) {
                            $('<p/>').text(file.name).appendTo(document.body);
                        });
                    },
                    process: [
                        {
                            action: 'load',
                            fileTypes: /^image\/(gif|jpeg|png)$/,
                            maxFileSize: 20000000 // 20MB
                        },
                        {
                            action: 'resize',
                            maxWidth: 1920,
                            maxHeight: 1080
                        },
                        {
                            action: 'save'
                        }
                    ]
                });
                $('#fileupload').bind('fileuploadsubmit', function (e, data) {
                    // The example input, doesn't have to be part of the upload form:
                    var GAL = $('#galleryId');
                    data.formData = {
                        galleryId: GAL.val(),
                        type: 'gallery',
                        entityId: 1
                    }
                    return true;
                });

                $(document).bind('dragover', function (e) {
                    var dropZone = $('#dropzone'),
                        timeout = window.dropZoneTimeout;
                    if (!timeout) {
                        dropZone.addClass('in');
                    } else {
                        clearTimeout(timeout);
                    }
                    if (e.target === dropZone[0]) {
                        dropZone.addClass('hover');
                    } else {
                        dropZone.removeClass('hover');
                    }
                    window.dropZoneTimeout = setTimeout(function () {
                        window.dropZoneTimeout = null;
                        dropZone.removeClass('in hover');
                    }, 100);
                });

                $(document).bind('drop dragover', function (e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                });
```

});

Things I'd love to achieve:

1. Resizing images at client side
2. Then send images with additional form data (data are not comming to server side script) to upload.php

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: All those things you mention are done within the PHP file. You have only posted your markup and JS. Where is the PHP handler?

Comment: I'm not getting it :) "Resizing images at client side" - done with PHP is server side. I do not know the workflow of this uploader, but I've expected something like: Select images, Images are resized at client side, uploaded to server with additional data, e.g. galleryId - upload.php - save some info into DB

Comment: Well no. Clientside you just select the file. Javascript can't access your local files (files stored on your computer). Javascript sends the information to the PHP-file and the PHP first uploads your file, then you can access it (and resize if you want to) and then store the correct and final image. I think this plugin has a PHP example.

Comment: Oh, thanks for explanation...so if I want to resize photo at client side, I have to use something like this http://www.plupload.com/index.php?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jquery File upload is not the right choice for my request. I'm now successfully using [Plupload](http://www.plupload.com/).

Comment: jQuery File Upload will do everything you want though the code is a little complex to understand at first.

Comment: Offering another library does not awnser the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?php 

    //Define some variables  
          $dir = "choice_images/"; 
          $types = array("image/gif","image/jpeg","image/pjpeg","image/png","application/x-zip-compressed");  
    //Check to determine if the submit button has been pressed  
        if(isset($_POST['submit'])){  

    //Shorten Variables  
         $pollids = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['pollid']);
         $choiceid= mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['chid']);   
         $tmp_name = $_FILES['realfile']['tmp_name'];  
         $new_name = $_FILES['realfile']['name'];
         if($new_name=="")
         {
             echo"<script>alert('Please choose file to upload');        
    </script>";

         }
     else {



    //Check MIME Type  
        if (in_array($_FILES['realfile']['type'], $types)){  


            $replacestring = str_replace(" ","_",$new_name);

         $img = time()."_".$replacestring;

         $datetime = date('m-d-Y');

//your codings

     //Move file from tmp dir to new location  
            move_uploaded_file($tmp_name,$dir . $img);  
            echo "{$_FILES['realfile']['name']} was uploaded sucessfully!";                                          
        }else{  
        //Print Error Message  
         echo "<small>File <strong><em>{$_FILES['realfile']['name']}</em></strong> Was Not Uploaded!</small><br />";  
        //Debug  
       $name =  $_FILES['realfile']['name'];  
       $type =    $_FILES['realfile']['type'];  
       $size =    $_FILES['realfile']['size'];  
       $tmp =     $_FILES['realfile']['name'];  
    //   echo "Name: $name<br/ >Type: $type<br />Size: $size<br />Tmp: $tmp";  
       echo"<script>alert('Please choose image file to upload. This is not a valid image file');       
    </script>";
        }  
        }
        }        
    else{        
    //    echo 'Could Not Upload Files';  
    }  

    ?>
```

You can use these coding for file upload with perfect validation and if you want to add functionality like resize image and so on it is possible within this coding.